# Printing array -- getting strange output (emu8086)

Tags: assembly, emu8086

My question is related to printing an array in assembly 8086 language.
I use 'emu8086' program.

The following piece seems fine to me (I'm a beginner), yet the result I get is:
*P000, instead of: 12345.

```
  Main:

A DB 1,2,3,4,5 //my array

SUB SI, SI    //SI stands for counter and index here
LEA BX, A  

loop3:
MOV DX, [BX + SI] 

ADD DX, 30h //converting digit into character
MOV Ah, 2h
int 21h    //displaying the character in console window

INC SI
CMP SI, 5
JNE loop3             

end Main
```

Can you, please, explain what's wrong with my function ?
Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1):

The program, in the question, is incomplete. There are two vital lines missing:

```
    MOV AX, @DATA
    MOV DS, AX
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330306/when-will-the-code-under-data-segment-execute-in-this-code) I found the purpose of these.

---

Below are listed the things that made me change the program.

1. I found a [good assembly program on this topic](http://www.dailyfreecode.com/code/array-display-content-inputted-496.aspx), based on which, step by step, I could analyze each line of code, and understand the meaning. I think this program explains everything.

There are some things I discovered:

- [Assembly language program should have a structure](http://showmecodes.blogspot.ro/2012/12/8086-assembly-program-structure.html)
- [Each register has its own purpose](http://www.eecg.toronto.edu/~amza/www.mindsec.com/files/x86regs.html)

---

So my program now looks this way:

```
    .MODEL SMALL
    .STACK 100H

    .DATA
    A DW 1, 2, 3, 4 ; it's my array

    .CODE   

    MAIN PROC

        MOV AX, @DATA
        MOV DS, AX


        LEA SI, A   ;set SI as offset address of A (of my array)
        MOV BX, 4   ;store the number of digits in BX register
        MOV CX, BX  ;CX is used as a loop counter

        LOOP1:

            MOV DX, [SI] ; Line 1
            ADD DX, 30h  ;convert digit to char and store in DX

            ;Print character stored in DX 
            MOV AH, 2h
            INT 21h

            ;Store in DX the ASCII code for 'space' character 
            MOV DX, 20h
            ;Print ' ' = space 
            INT 21h 


            ADD SI, 2 ;SI = SI + 2

        LOOP LOOP1 ; jump to label 'LOOP1' while CX != 0

    MAIN ENDP
```

- The meaning for *Line 1* I found [here](http://www.uobabylon.edu.iq/uobcoleges/ad_downloads/5_25278_37.pdf).
- [Here](http://showmecodes.blogspot.ro/2012/12/input-and-output-in-8086-assembly.html) I found what instructions to use for printing characters, with all the explanations.
- The [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/) was helpful.
- About [LOOP](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-3773/instructionset-72/index.html) instruction.

Comment: You learned a lot, yet you ignore the fact that the DOS display function __only operates on the DL register, not the DX register__.

Comment: Why does your little program even bother to use the BX register?

Comment: @Fifoernik Thank you for remarks. I think I should learn more about assembly.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to verify that the `DS` register is loaded with the proper value, or your memory reads will be from the wrong segment.

Comment: Hi. I've applied the change that you suggested, but nothing changed. It's the same output again.

Answer (score 0):

```
.MODEL SMALL
.DATA

    ARRAY DW 1,2,3,4,5
.CODE
.STARTUP

  MOV CX,5      

 MOV SI,OFFSET ARRAY

LOP:
    MOV DX,[SI]  
    ADD DX,30H

    MOV AH,2H
    INT 21H  

    INC SI 
    INC SI

LOOP LOP
.EXIT
END
```

TRY THIS