# print elements of array in assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, emu8086

I am new in assembly , I am using **emu8086**

I was trying to print two elements of an array , but I could not print the second element

Here is my code:

```
.MODEL SMALL

.STACK 100H  

.DATA 
MSG DB 'HI','GOOD$'

.CODE 

MAIN PROC

MOV AX,@DATA
MOV DS,AX
 
MOV AH,2
MOV DL,MSG
INT 21H  

MOV AH,2
MOV DL,MSG+1
INT 21H 

MOV AH,4CH
INT 21H

MAIN ENDP

END MAIN
```

at output hi is printed , good is not printed . please correct me how can print the second element.

Comment: You can loop through the whole array and print the value of offset.

Check this link:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35709437/printing-array-getting-strange-output-emu8086)

Comment: 1) `int 21h / ah=02h` prints individual characters, to print a string you would use `int 21h / ah=09h`. 2) All strings that you print with `int 21h / ah = 09h` need to be `'$'`-terminated; currently only `'GOOD'` is `'$`-terminated. 3) `'GOOD'` starts at `MSG+2`, not `MSG+1` (and if you add a `'$'`-terminator to `'HI'`, `'GOOD'` would start at `MSG+3`). It would simplify things if you created another array containing the address of each string, which you then could process in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is print "HIGOOD" then write:

```
MOV AH,2
MOV DL,MSG
INT 21H  
MOV DL,MSG+1
INT 21H
MOV DL,MSG+2
INT 21H  
MOV DL,MSG+3
INT 21H
MOV DL,MSG+4
INT 21H  
MOV DL,MSG+5
INT 21H
```

A far better approach is to "$"-terminate both strings like `MSG DB 'HI$','GOOD$'` and then use the string output function 09h:

```
MSG DB 'HI$','GOOD$'
...
mov ah, 09h
mov dx, offset MSG
int 21h
mov dx, offset MSG+3
int 21h
```

Even better is to assign separate labels to your strings:

```
MSG1 DB 'HI$'
MSG2 DB 'GOOD$'
...
mov ah, 09h
mov dx, offset MSG1
int 21h
mov dx, offset MSG2
int 21h
```