# operands type do not match -TASM

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

When assembling this code in TASM I get the error *operands type do not match*

```
  data segment
    data1 db 02
    data2 db 03
    res1 db ?
    res2 db ?
data ends 

code segment
    assume cs:code,ds:data
    start: 
    mov ax,data1
    mov ds,ax
    mov al,data1
    mov bl,data2
    add al,bl
    mov res1,al
    mov ah,data1
    mov bh,data2
    sub ah,bh
    mov res2,ah
    int 3
code ends
end star
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please edit your question so it is easier to read: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: TASM (and MASM) keeps track of types where it can. You define `data1` as a DB (byte) and then this `mov ax,data1` fails to assemble because MASM sees that you are trying to move a byte to a a 16bit register. Source and destination have to be the same size.

Comment: While what @MichaelPetch says is true, it's not really the heart of your problem.  You are trying to load the correct value into `ds` (called the Data Segment register), and this isn't quite how you do that.  I don't use tasm, but according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10407190/2189500), you can use `mov ax,@data`.  Note that while none of your variables are named data, the "segment" they are all in is named data. @data is (apparently) the way tasm lets you refer to the segment.  Loading ds like this tells the cpu what segment holds all your data items.

Comment: `@data` only applies if you use `.data` to start a data section. If you manually declare a `data` section as the OP has you have two options to get the segment value: `mov ax, data` (without the `@`) or indirectly by specifying `seg`  and the name of a label. `mov ax, seg data1` would move the value of the segment in which `data1` resides which happens to be `data` (of course the value of a segment isn't fully realized until it is fixed up by the DOS EXE(MZ) loader at runtime)